# Context is not working properly in dialogflow

Tags: node.js, dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

```
const contextlist = 'customer';
app.intent('Welcome', (conv) => {
    const customer = { 'companyId': '11131' };
    conv.contexts.set(contextlist, 5, customer);
});


app.intent('Delivery',(conv)=>{
let companycontext = conv.contexts.get(contextlist);
})
```

[These are the logs regarding the context](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pPOwB.png)

I'm going to set the context when my welcome intent is called and getting the value from intent when the Delivery intent will call, But I'm getting undefined at the time of getting context value.

Answer (score 0):

First try adding a conv.ask() call with some text, in the code example you showed you are not returning a response, this might affect the setting of the context.

If that doesn't work, try changing the way you are setting your variables in your context to the following:

```
conv.contexts.set(contextlist, 5, { customer });
```

The properties that you want to set need to be part of an object. If you want to retrieve the customer, you need to use the following code:

```
// Set context
conv.contexts.set(contextlist, 5, { customer });

// Retrieve context
const companycontext = conv.contexts.get(contextlist);
const customer = companycontext.parameters.customer;
```